# Can't properly send vars in AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a button after a input type text meant to write a new categorie (id='new_cat'), so, I got this ajax code, and isn't sending the variables

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn_new_cat', function(){
    var new_cat = $('#new_cat').val();
        var id = '<?php echo $not_cat_id; ?>';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'dist/scripts/add_cat.php',
            data: {
                cat_id:id,
                new_cat: new_cat
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
});
```

add_cat.php

```
<?php
include "../../session.php";

$add_cat = $_POST['new_cat'];
$not_cat_id = $_POST['cat_id'];

 $sql_ins_cat = "INSERT INTO categories(title) VALUES (:cat)";
    $ins_cat = $conn->prepare($sql_ins_cat );
    $ins_cat ->bindParam(":cat", $add_cat);
    $ins_cat ->execute();

    echo $not_tipo_id;

?>
```

Thanks

NOTE: I'm on local, they are sending as empty to add_cat.php, so, all I got on success is a white space, is inserting aswell empty in DB (mysql). In add_cat.php I'm only making a echo from vars

Comment: what do you mean, "not sending"? They don't show up in php's $_POST? you used a network sniffer and they weren't present in the request while it was on the wire?

Comment: I'm on localhost, they are sending and "working" but with EMPTY, so what i get on success is only a white space. In add_cat.php I'm only making a echo from vars

Comment: where/when is $not_cat_id set? Can you echo it elsewhere on the page or is it supposed to change with some action on the page by the user?

Comment: $not_cat_id is set in the very beggining of the page, and yeah, I can echo that where I want, working well, showing the respective id, and is pasing well to the vars created in the function above

Comment: Show us the PHP code (add_cat.php).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing

**contentType** attribute in ajax method.

as you are passing json it should be "application/json"

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'dist/scripts/add_cat.php',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: {
                cat_id:id,
                new_cat: new_cat
            },

            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```